# How to print dictionary by key when some keys have multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large dictionary and am only trying to print the keys that have multiple values. For each value, I would like to print on a new line.

I tried iterating through the dictionary, but I'm not sure how to go through the individual values when you get to a certain key.

```
for i, n in errorDict.items():
    if len(errorDict[i]) > 1:
        print (i)
        n=0
        while n < len(errorDict[i]):
            print (errorDict[i](n))
            n += 1
```

I would like the end result to look like this.

```
Model1
ErrorCode1
ErrorCode2
ErrorCode3

Model2
ErrorCode1
ErrorCode2

Model3
ErrorCode1
ErrorCode2
ErrorCode3
ErrorCode4
ErrorCode5
```

Comment: what does you errorDict look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify/correct your code to this:

```
for key, values in errorDict.items():
  if len(values) > 1:
    print(key)
    for v in values:
      print(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, n in errorDict.items():
    if len(n) > 1:
        print (i)
        for val in n:
            print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in errorDict.keys():
    if len(errorDict.get(item)) > 1:
        print(item)
        for item2 in dict.get(item):
            print(item2)
```

You need to use the `keys()` method to get the keys and then iterate over it to get the item corresponding to the key and check for your necessary condition.